# How can I improve the results of such a binomial test? Was it a good choice for this problem?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| initial | final | division | fsa | hrs_prev | fsa/hrs_prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 2020-06 | A | 0 | 168 | 0 |
| 2020-01 | 2020-06 | B | 14,29 | 177,45 |  |
| 2020-02 | 2020-07 | A | 9,52 | 177,45 | 0,054 |

and so on

- `Initial` and `final` refers to an interval of six months. There are such intervals for division A and B throught `2020-01` to `2021-12`
- `Division` refers to subsets A and B, which are companies, of a larger company G
- `fsa` refers to absenteeism of an employee in the interval and are given in hours
- `hrs_prev` are the total working time of this employee through the six months interval and are also given in hours
- `fsa / hrs_prev` is just the ratio of those two variables

My goal is to answer the question: *is the absenteeism in the sub company A (B) comparable to the absenteeism in the whole company G?*

Treating absenteeism as a coin, with heads or tails, I want to perform a binomial test to verify if in the given six months interval the absenteeism in A are larger or smaller than the absenteeism in the whole company G. I want to find if in some division of the whole company the absenteeism deviate from what it is expected, through a confidence level of 10%.

To to this I considered `fsa >= 4` as 'heads' in a coin toss, and `fsa < 4` as tails. That is, more than 4 hours of absence was considered absenteeism and less than 4 no.

To perform a binomial test I need proportions of heads and tails in a game of n toss:

```
heads = df.loc[df[fsa] >= df['hrs_prev']*0.02]
tails = df.loc[df[fsa] < df['hrs_prev']*0.02]
proportion = len(heads)/(len(heads)+len(tails))
```

-- 0.02 times `hrs_prev` means that I am taking as absenteeism just the number of total hours that is more than 2% of the predicted working hours for that interval. Then, it is classified as 'heads' (absenteeism), rather than 'tails' (no absenteeism).

For the whole dataset.
For the subsets A and B:

```
heads_emp = heads.loc[heads['division'] == 'A']
tails_emp = tails.loc[tails['division'] == 'B']
total = len(heads_emp) + len(tails_emp)
```

Thus `proportion` is the proportion of heads and tails through the entire dataset in that interval (something like 60 / 60+40 for 100 lines with 60 heads and 40 tails). And total is the sum of heads and tails in the subset considering just division A (that is, 20 + 15, for example if 20 was the number of heads and 15 the number of tails).

The binomial test is then:

```
bin_pvalue_g = stats.binomtest(k=len(heads_emp), n=total,
                               p=proportion,
                               alternative='greater')

bin_pvalue_s = stats.binomtest(k=len(heads_emp), n=total,
                               p=proportion,
                               alternative='less')
```

That is, to compare the number of results that was 'heads' in division A I counted the `total` tosses and to compare with the number of heads in the whole dataset. It is like comparing a coin `X` with a coin `Y` to test for fairness of coin `Y` in comparison to a given coin `X` that we know.

My questions are:

- Does it make sense?
- Is this a correct use of a binomial test? If so, how can I improve it or make it better or the results, the `p-value` in this case, is what it is and are the better thing I can take from this kind of problem?

The results, if it is of any interest to the question are given in the following table:

| initial | final | division | p-value greater | p-value less |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 2020-06 | A | 1 | 3,66E^-23 |
| 2020-02 | 2020-07 | A | 1 | 3,66E^-28 |
| 2020-03 | 2020-08 | A | 1 | 5,27^E-40 |
| 2020-01 | 2020-06 | B | 0,46 | 0,54 |
| 2020-02 | 2020-07 | B | 0,08 | 0,95 |
| 2020-03 | 2020-08 | B | 0,28 | 0,72 |

and so on

There are other variables. Other than `fsa` I mean, but they are all in hours. And there other divisions, like C, D and E. But the data are no different from what I reproduced here. The results for A are all in such a way: 1 and 0 basically. For B it seems 'better'. The results for C and D are exactly like A and the results for E are in such a way that looks more like B.

- did I messed up with the test or it seems reasonable? For `A` it is like the `p-values` for `alternative='greater'` are telling me that absenteeism are not deviating at all, but for "less" I cannot reject the null hypothesis because the p-values are zero. In all intervals of six months.
- But for division B (and E) sometimes they are 0,45 or 0,85 but sometimes they are 0,05 or 0,02 which are telling me that in some intervals everything is fine but in some of them I must reject the null hypothesis and look closely to that division because absenteeism is deviating a lot from the expected. Which seems fine, I do expect that some six months intervals will be different and bring some deviating values in absenteeism; it is just the columns of p-values giving only 1 and 0 that seems strange. Or it is just counter intuitive or I made something wrong.
- There are some inversions like in the first six month interval the p-value greater is 0 and then in the next six month interval the p-value greater becomes 1; what is strange is that six month interval in this case differ from the other by only one month (the first interval is jan-2019 to jun-2019 and the second is feb-2019 to jul-2019 and so on).

Any comments, tips or help or corrections would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Absenteeism is a matter of degree.  It is not appropriate to dichotomize it.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of agree with you, because there are many levels of absenteeism, but at a first aproach I could not find a better solution to test it with p-values. Maybe add more levels, like not treating it as a coin with two levels but as a 'dice' with n levels? I want to improve the solution, the only constraint being that I need to be able to validate it with some statistical test